# Compiling Open Office XML For Mono

Tags: .net, mono, openxml-sdk

Steps I followed:

1) git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK.git

2) sudo bash build.open-xml-sdk.sh

I see at the very beginning of the output that the nuget command is not found. And then at the end of the output I am told that XUnit is missing.

How do I go about resolving these dependency problems.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr).

Output:

```
sudo bash build.open-xml-sdk.sh

build.open-xml-sdk.sh: line 4: nuget: command not found
XBuild Engine Version 12.0
Mono, Version 3.2.8.0
Copyright (C) 2005-2013 Various Mono authors
Build started 5/17/2016 5:35:15 PM.
```

.... success steps and warnings .....

Errors:

```
/home/cmagnollay/mono/Open-XML-SDK/Open-XML-SDK.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/cmagnollay/mono/Open-XML-SDK/System.IO.Packaging.Tests/System.IO.Packaging.Tests.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    Tests.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

/home/cmagnollay/mono/Open-XML-SDK/Open-XML-SDK.sln (default targets) ->
(Build target) ->
/home/cmagnollay/mono/Open-XML-SDK/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WB.Tests/DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WB.Tests.csproj (default targets) ->
/usr/lib/mono/xbuild/12.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->

    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/BaseFixture.cs(31,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/Common/VerifiableLog.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/ChartTrackingRefBased/ChartTrackingRefBasedTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/CommentExPeople/CommentExPeopleTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/CommentEx/CommentExTest.cs(21,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/ContentControl/ContentControlTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/FootnoteColumns/FootnoteColumnTest.cs(5,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/General/ConformanceTestBase.cs(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/Guide/GuideTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/Pivot/PivotTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/PresetTransition/PresetTransitionTest.cs(6,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/Slicer/SlicerTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/Theme/ThemeTest.cs(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/ThreadingInfo/ThreadingInfoTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/Timeline/TimeLineTest.cs(14,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/WebExtension/WebExtensionTest.cs(27,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ConformanceTest/WorkbookPr/WorkBookPrTest.cs(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/CreateFromTemplateFixture.cs(27,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/FlatOpcFixture.cs(28,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/IsoStrictTest/IsoStrictTest.cs(21,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/AllParticleValidatorTest.cs(10,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/AnyParticleValidatorTest.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/BugRegressionTest.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/ChoiceParticleValidatorTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/CompositeParticleValidatorTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/CustomXmlElementTest.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/GroupParticleValidatorTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/ListValueTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/M4Conformance.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/MCSupport.cs(7,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/McValidationTest.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlCompositeElementTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlElementTest.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlElementTest2.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlPackageTest.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlPartTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlReaderTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlSimpleValueTest2.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlValidatorTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlWriterTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/SchemaValidatorTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/SdbSchemaDatasTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/SemanticConstraintTest.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/SemanticValidationTest.cs(5,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/SequenceParticleValidatorTest.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/XmlPathTest.cs(6,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OFCatTest/Robustness.cs(22,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTaskLibrary/TestScripts/OpenXmlTestBase.cs(21,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/AutoSaveTestClass.cs(20,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/CodeGenSanityTest.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/DocumentTraverseTest.cs(11,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/GenerateList4LowLevelTest.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/MarkupCompatibilityTest.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/OpenXmlCompositeElementTestClass.cs(19,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/OpenXmlDomTestBase.cs(16,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/OpenXmlReaderWriterTest.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/OpenXmlRootElementTestClass.cs(15,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/OpenXmlDomTest/SimpleTypeTest.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/SaveAndCloneFixture.cs(32,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/TestDocx01.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/TestGeneratedCode.cs(9,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/TestPptx01.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/TestXlsx01.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Xunit' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
    ../DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Tests/ofapiTest/OpenXmlValidatorTest.cs(33,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IClassFixture' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Comment: please copy+paste the output that shows those errors

Comment: @knocte Ok, I posted those. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a partial answer that I hope someone can improve on:

You can download nuget.exe, a .net assembly, from [nuget download website](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html), (I used v3.4.4) and run it under mono something like this: `mono ~/Downloads/nuget.exe restore Open-XML-SDK.sln`. This allows nuget to run, but with errors. e.g.:

`Errors in packages.config projects
    Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'xunit.assert'.
      ~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'xunit.assert.2.0.0' is not found on source '~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
      Error: TrustFailure
    Unable to find version '2.0.0' of package 'xunit'.
      ~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache: Package 'xunit.2.0.0' is not found on source '~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
      Error: TrustFailure`